# Weird Promise Chaining Case: then() parameter is undefined, last chain data not returned

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

First of all, I would like to apologize for not being able to expose my original code here, due to the following reasons:

1. It's too lengthy.
2. It contains sensitive business information.

However, I believe the following outline should be enough to describe something weird happen to my promise chaining code (see the comments in code):

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    return somePromiseFunction()
       .then(async allAccSummaries => {
          // Some very lengthy codes here.
          // Contains several await function calls.
    
          let batchResult = { 
             // Some property assignments here 
          };
          console.log(batchResult); // Confirmed batchResult is NOT undefined.
          return resolve(batchResult); // This was the result returned to the caller instead!
       })
       .then(prevBatchResult => {
          console.log(prevBatchResult); // prevBatchResult is undefined, why?
    
          // Some other very lengthy logics here.
    
          let finalBatchResult = { 
             // Some property assignments here 
          };
          return finalBatchResult; // This was not returned to caller as final result!
    
       }

}
```

I wonder how can this be possibly happened? I know that the only reason for the `then()` parameter to be `undefined` is when the previous `then()` was not returning anything, but this isn't true for my case. Also, I want the result of the **final `then()`** to be returned to the caller, not the first one. Can somebody point out to me any possibility that can cause this to happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if this is directly related to your issue but it's the first thing I noticed in your code: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> console.log(prevBatchResult); // prevBatchResult is undefined, why?
> ```

Because the return value of the previous `then()` function is `return resolve(batchResult);` and the `resolve(...)` function returns `undefined`.

Your problem is caused by the [explicit-construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803744/19068).

- Remove `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` (and the matching `});`.
- Don't call `resolve` just return the value (`batchResult`) you want to resolve the promise with.